# Deprecated: Function eregi_replace('http://', $pattern, $Url);

Tags: php

can any one tell me how to change this eregi function into preg_match I am getting an error

> Deprecated: Function eregi() is deprecated in /home/techorb1/public_html/product/includes/modules/payment/cavenue.php on line 61
>
> Deprecated: Function eregi_replace() is deprecated in /includes/modules/payment/cavenue.php on line 62

```
if(!(eregi($pattern,$Url,$reg)))
    eregi_replace('http://', $pattern, $Url);
```

after lil research i found this changing

```
if(!(eregi($pattern,$Url,$reg)))
```

to

```
if(!(preg_match("#".$pattern."#",$Url,$reg)))
```

solve or hide line 61 prob i dont know coding or php  but i think it solve the first prob please help me to solve second prob of preg_replace

Comment: I wonder if the manual page has anything to say about this: http://php.net/manual/en/function.eregi-replace.php.

Comment: Please use proper markdown for your code! This is really hard to read...

Comment: NO SIR THIS IS NOT MY CODE I EVEN DON'T KNOW ANY CODING.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need to match if pattern exists in the string, just run replace function. Change:

```
if(!(eregi($pattern,$Url,$reg)))
    eregi_replace('http://', $pattern, $Url);
```

with:

```
preg_replace("#".$pattern."#i", 'http://', $Url);
```

Comment: Thankyou Glavić you helped me a lot. I don't know anything about php or another these kind of coding but you all people helped me very much. coz of your help i was able to code my online store programming. THANK YOU ALL.